# Neural-Networks - preferred method for training, classification v.s. regression

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, regression, gradient-descent

As a conclusion of their paper "Efficient Backprop" (http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf) (§10 Discussion and Conclusion), LeCun and others conlude that the preferred method for training [a] network should be picked as follow :

- If the training set is large and redundant and if the task is classification, use stochastic gradient or the stochastic Levenberg Marquardt method.
- If the training set is not too large, or if the task is regression, use conjugate gradient.

I was quite surprised about this conclusion because, from §6. to §9. they describe those algorithms, and discuss their performance, mostly trough the lens of eigenvalues of the Hessian. There is no real discussion about regression v.s. classification, except for the end of §6.2 on conjugate gradient: "Clearly on large and redundant (classification) problems stochastic backpropagation is faster".

Can someone point how that is "clear" for classification (but not regression) ? Doesn't that rely on some important assumptions (balanced classes, classes separability, de-correlation of variables) ?